# Error Checking - Java

Tags: java

I am having a problem error checking if a date is valid.

I have tried the code below but I am still getting an error.

```
if (sales == null || sales != "mm/dd/yyyy" {
    errors.add("phone", new ActionMessage("error.sales.required"));
}
```

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis `)` after "mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: What is the error message, it seems you are missing a closing parenthesis after the date comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I just write this like this but you can customize the regex to match the correct date. This below is for date format like 12/30/2004. It will take any two numbers for month and date. You may need to go one step further to customize it so it doesn't take input values that are greater than 31 for days or values that would be beyond 12 for a month value.

```
String sales = "12/12/2004";
if (sales == null || !sales.matches("\\d{2}\\/{1}\\d{2}\\/{1}\\d{4}")){
    System.out.println("Sale is null or date format doesn't match");     
}
```

With this one below you can have one digit for the month value and one digit for date value, and the regex would still pass the input value.

```
!sales.matches("\\d{1,2}\\/{1}\\d{1,2}\\/{1}\\d{4}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this function which will parse the date given in string format with required format. Returns true if able to parse or else false. Replace your code `sales != "mm/dd/yyyy"` with `isValidDateFormat(sales, "MM/dd/yyyy")`.

```
 public static boolean isValidDateFormat(final String data, final String dateFormat){
        try{
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);  
            formatter.format(date);
            return true;
        }
        catch(final ParseException ex){
            return false;
        }
    }
```